# CSS selector and XPath in Selenium Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How about using CSS selector in Selenium Python if I am not getting id or name or class of that HTML element ? How about preferring CSS in comparison to XPath?

Answer (score 5):

No idea what you are trying to ask here. I can only take a guess.

> How about using css selector in Selenium Python if I am not getting id
>   or name or class of that html element ?

If you are testing a complex web application, you have to learn CSS Selector and/or XPath. Yes, other locating methods are somewhat limited.

> How about preferring CSS in comparison to xpath?

Generally speaking, CSS Selectors are always in favor of XPath, because

- CSS Selectors are more elegant, more readable
- CSS Selectors are faster
- XPath engines are different in each browser
- IE does not have a native xpath engine

However, there are situations XPath is the only way to go. For example

- Find element by its text
- Find element from its descendants (if there are no other better methods)
- Few other rare situations

Comment: @selenium_user: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?